# Afriat theorem for negative goods

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, decision-theory, choice-theory, demand

GARP and Afrait theorem assume that the alternative $x\in\mathbb R_+$ is always positive. In some economic contexts, such as financial choices, the attribute can be negative.

I wonder if we can naturally relax the $\mathbb R_+$ constraint. i.e. let $x\in\mathbb R$,

GARP: if $p_i⋅x_{i+1}≤p_i⋅x_i$ for $i∈\{1,...,N−1\}$ and $p_N⋅x_1≤p_N⋅x_N$, then those inequalities must be equalities.

At a first glance, the generalization to negative number seems plausible and not problematic.

Comment: I think if you allow prices to be negative in GARP, then requiring $x\in\mathbb R_+$ is without loss of generality.

Comment: @HerrK. You mean allowing $x\in\mathbb R$ and $p\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: I mean $x\in\mathbb R_+$ and $p\in \mathbb R$.